# How to retrieve data from assets folder

Tags: c#, file, exception, file-io, uwp

I'm building an app where I stored some data in **JSON** format in the Assets folder. Now when my app meets a specific requirement, it should read the file, deserialize and show the data.

Here is the code that I have written-

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"Assets\appleTree.json");
string data = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DataModel));
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
var result = (DataModel)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

The problem is, at line no 1, program throws this exception -

**Value does not fall within the expected range**

How can I resolve this problem?

> Before posting here, I searched online and couldn't find any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync`([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync)) method to access the `Assets` folder. E.g:

```cs
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/GuitarTest1.mp3")
);
```

(See a little more in 
[Mark Heath's blog post with this topic](https://markheath.net/post/accessing-bundled-content-in-uwp-applications))